# question on one-to-many communication using rosservice

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As known from the ROS documentation, message/topic is used for multi-to-multi but one-way  communication, while service is recommended in case of request/reply. I suppose ros service is mainly used for one-to-one two-way transport. Then is ros service also suitable for one-to-many communication?

With a simple test program (adapted from the ros service server/client example program in tutorial), I observed that it's no problem for a single ros server to accept multiple client requests from different computers.

Then I can't help wondering that if certain variables/resources on the server side need be processed as response to client request, will a mutex be enough to make sure the shared resources can be properly handled. How does ros service handle requests in the bottom level, like queue?

thanks for the hints/advices in advance.

clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10747/question-on-one-to-many-communication-using-rosservice/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Section 4.1 on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) - the first point hints at the fact that services are handled by the normal spinning, i.e. they will be processed in order and not in parallel.

Then everything should go smooth without mutexes.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2